# How to add a popup menu to a JTextField

Tags: java

Can anybody explain me how to add a popup menu at a JtextField? I managed to add a JPopupMenu:

```
JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
    popup.add("m");
popup.add("n"); 

JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.add(popup);
```

.....

But when i roll the mouse over "popup", nothing is happening (i need to select an item from popup).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your comment, it sounds like you are trying to display a sub-menu in the popup that appears over your JTextField.

```
// 1. Let's add the initial popup to the text field.
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
textField.add(popup);
textField.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);

// 2. Let's create a sub-menu that "expands"
JMenu subMenu = new JMenu("m");
subMenu.add("m1");
subMenu.add("m2");

// 3. Finally, add the sub-menu and item to the popup
popup.add(subMenu);
popup.add("n");
```

Hopefully I answered the question you are trying to ask.  If not could you explain a bit more on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you sure that `textField.add(popup);` is needed here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its as straightforward as the code in question looks. 
You may want to have a look at this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AutocompleteTextField.htm)

Comment: No. I need to expand a pop-up menu. In your link the example below, is not a popup menu to JTextField. But i am looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [editable combo box](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) could suit you better.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the JComponent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu%28javax.swing.JPopupMenu%29) for the `setComponentPopupMenu()` method.